# Why would a test run in NUNIT but not in Visual Studio Unit Tester?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, nunit

We have a debug project that runs tests designed for N-Unit.  When we run the same tests through the Visual Studio debugger (with resharper), it fails.

The code uses selenium.  The call where it fails is the call to instantiate a Fire Fox Driver:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

The exception thrown is curious.  It says "{"The system cannot find the file specified"}"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you use google chrome as the browser, then you can use visual studio unit tester, but if you use firefox as the testing browser, you can only use NUNit

Comment: You mention resharper as well as "Visual Studio Unit Tester." What exactly do you mean by the latter? What do you mean when you say "you can only use NUnit?" That is, exactly what programs are you running in each case.